# Empty TextViews in CardViews when in release build

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, release

My app compiles without any errors on both release and debugs builds. Works absolutely perfect in debug but when I build for play store (release) my RecyclerViews look like this:

[Screenshot RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja0AF.jpg)

Furthermore, when I click any card to edit it, TextViews in the edit screen remains empty also. What can cause this behavior?

app>build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'

check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.1'
    implementation project(":internal:lintchecks")
    implementation project(":internal:chooser")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: please add `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Comment: There can be many reasons for this, you will need to provide more information. For example do you use proguard?

Comment: @hardartcore I've disabled proguard in build.gradle

Comment: As far as I can see from your build.gradle file it's enabled.

Comment: thanks, good call hardartcore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `minifyEnabled` to `false`

```
android {

//...

  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false

          //...   
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: That caused the App to crash on startup 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-a3-mfpb3f8SZ13Ji4PA-Fg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-a3-mfpb3f8SZ13Ji4PA-Fg==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]

Comment: @Jace try `Invalidate Caches / Restart` in AndroidStudio > File